# Fetch nested node data using AJAX call

Tags: html

I tried to create table using JSON data, I am not sure how to fetch nested node data using AJAX call?

```
{
"id": 1,
"label": "A",
"child1": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "B",
        "child2.1": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "label": "B"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "label": "B"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "label": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"child2": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "C"
    }
],
"child3": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "label": "D",
        "child4.1": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "label": "B"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "label": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How am I able to fetch this data in to a table. I tried this way but it is throwing an error.

```
 alert();
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


var url = "{
"id": 1,
"label": "A",
"child1": [{
        "id": 2,"label": "B",
        "child2.1": [{
                "id": 5,
                "label": "B"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "label": "B"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "label": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"child2": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "C"
    }
],
"child3": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "label": "D",
        "child4.1": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "label": "B"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "label": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
  }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
var i;
var out = "<table>";
var z = arr.length;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" +
    arr[i].id +
    alert(i);
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].City +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Country +
    "</td></tr>";
 }
 out += "</table>";
 document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

I even tried to debug using `alert();` but it is not working. alert is not working, I don't have any idea, where is the mistake.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: woha where to start. First off that's not a url, why is the url a json response? Second quotations dont match. If you're using a code editor it would have shown you something's wrong because the colors weren't right.

Comment: Atually, It is not throwing any error but , even it is not working. not even alert ,pop up.

Comment: If native functions are not working, there is mostly a javascript error somewhere. Look into the console.

Comment: The javascript is not being executed as there is a syntax error. Where you define the variable `url` please remove the opening & closing quotation mark wrapping the object (it is not json).